# jQueryUI AutoComplete results list springs back to top when attempting to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm attempting to customize the rendering of the dropdown list of results of a jQueryUI AutoComplete widget to achieve a grid-like display style, using CSS to limit the height and allow scrolling (combining `max-height` with `overflow-y: scroll`) but I'm experiencing a weird behavior with scrolling the dropdown itself: it automatically scrolls back to top and/or the scrolling happens just moving the mouse over the list itself.

[You can click here to see a repro on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23r5J/), or see below (code can be put in a local html file and run). To test the autocomplete, enter the string **val** in the textboxes.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Behavior seems consistent across jQuery/UI versions --> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) items.push('val' + i);
    var reference = $('#in1').autocomplete({ source: items });
    var broken = $('#in2').autocomplete({ source: items }).data('ui-autocomplete');

    var renderItem = function(ul,item) {
        var $li = $('<li />'); 
        var $a = $('<a />').css({width: '270px', float:'left', clear: 'both', padding:'0'}).appendTo($li);
        //Build fake "columns"
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
            var $span = $('<span />').html('[Col'+i+item.value+'] ').appendTo($a);

        return $li.appendTo(ul);
    }
    broken._renderItem = renderItem;    
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
* { font-family: Arial; font-size:12px; }
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<body>
<strong>enter 'val' to test</strong>
SCROLLS OK: <input id="in1" type="text" /> SCROLLS WEIRD: <input id="in2" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

I went back to the basics and re-checked the [autocomplete page](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) but AFAIK my code is correct. What's going on here ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by adding `float:'left'`?

Answer (score 1):

Well I can tell you what is causing the issue.

Its caused by adding `float:'left'` in the following line:

```
var $a = $('<a />').css({width: '270px', /*float:'left',*/ clear: 'both', padding:'0'}).appendTo($li);
```